# How to display the current applied coupon slug in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hyperlink, coupon

**My goal** : Retrieve the coupon code applied (only one coupon code can be applied on the cart page) and create a custom link 'Remove Coupon'.

**My problem** : I can't figure out how to display in my 'Remove Coupon' link's href the current applied coupon slug.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

To get the applied coupon(s) name(s) linked with remove url, you can simply use something like:

```php
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) {
    $page_url     = is_checkout() ? wc_get_checkout_url() : wc_get_cart_url();
    $remove_url   = esc_url( add_query_arg( 'remove_coupon', rawurlencode( $code ), $page_url ) );

    echo '<a href="'. $remove_url .'" data-coupon="'. esc_attr($code) .'">' . __("Remove coupon") . ' "' . esc_html($code) .'"</a>';
}
```

So there is everything here to get the coupon code and the remove link… It should work.